# For Hilbert spaces, does weak analyticity with respect to a dense subspace of functionals imply analyticity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Let $i : X \hookrightarrow Y$ be a dense embedding of complex Hilbert spaces.

> Let $f : \mathbb{D} \to X$ be a function, such that $i \circ f$ is holomorphic ($\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk). Is $f$ necessarily holomorphic?

Here is what I know so far:

- By a standard Baire argument, $f$ is holomorphic on a dense open subset $U \subset \mathbb{D}$.
- There are counterexamples for $X$ Banach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This is stated in Arendt and Nikolski [Vector-valued holomorphic functions revisited. Math. Z. 234 (2000), no. 4, 777–805] Theorem 1.6:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space which is continuously embedded
>   into another Banach space $Z$. If $X$ is not closed in $Z$, then there exists a
>   function $f : \mathbb D \to X$ which not holomorphic, such that 
>   $f:\mathbb D \to Z$ is
>   holomorphic.

They write that this is due I. Globevnik for the case $X = \ell_p , Z =
\ell_q$
and to Wrobel in the general case, *however
with a more complicated proof*.